# How could I use the libraries of Google ML Kit in a xamarin.android application?

Tags: xamarin.android, google-mlkit

I am trying to do a xamarin.android application to use ML Kit, and I am folloing this steps:

1.- I create my android application in visual studio, using the template for that.
2.- In the nuget manager, I add the Xamarin.GooglePlayService.MLKit.BarcodeScanning

[According with google documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android), one step it is configure the scanner, for example with this code:

```
val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(
                Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC)
        .build()
```

Then problem is that I can't have access to BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder.

I have tried to add the using Xamarin.GooglePlayService.MLKit.BarcodeScanning, but I don't have this namespace available.

So I wondering how I could use the bardcode sacnner of ML Kit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience on xamarin.android. By google searching, looks the namespace is Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can using Xamarin.Google because it is not available. Also, I have download this example from their project: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/tree/master/samples/com.google.android.gms/play-services-vision but in a using I have the same problem, I don't have access to some namespaces so I can't compile.

Comment: The sample project you linked is the deprecated Mobile Vision rather MLKit.
https://developers.google.com/vision

Anyway, I'd suggest you to ask this in Xamarin community and I do saw some similar requests related to this, e.g. https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/932

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't know it was a deprecated example. I have read the link that you tell me, but they closed because it library was added. But I can't find any example of how to use MLKit.

Comment: Here's another related question that might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66613801/which-is-the-difference-between-the-two-googleplayservices-of-the-nuget-pacakges