# Which is the difference between the two GooglePlayServices of the nuget pacakges?

Tags: xamarin, google-mlkit

I wanted to use the QR scanner of the MLKit of Google, and in the nuget manager I have found two packagese. The two packager are:

Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning v116.1.0 which description is: Xamarin.Android Bindings for Google Play Services - Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.MLKit.BarcodeScanning v116.1.3 which desciption is: Xamarin.Android Bindings for Google Play Services - MLKit.BarcodeScanning

Which is the difference between Google Play Services and Google.MLKit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning**, there are some dependencies, the **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.MLKit.BarcodeScanning** is one of dependencies, you can get this from the following screenshot:

[image]

**About Nuget dependencies:**

When you install a NuGet package into a sdk style .NET Standard 2.0 project no references will be directly added to your project file (.csproj). Instead just a PackageReference will be added. The assemblies from the NuGet package will still be used at build time but will not be added directly to the project file directly.

NuGet will also only add the single PackageReference for the package installed. Unlike using a packages.config file it will not add all the dependencies to your project file but they will be implicitly used.

Comment: If I guess correctly, Xamarin.Google.MLKit.BarcodeScanning is mapping to the model-bundled version and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.MLKit.BarcodeScanning is the unbundled one listed at
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android

Comment: could you help me on this qustion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651260/choosing-proper-technology-for-building-multi-platform-application-for-both-desk